# Clicar e agir, clicar novamente e voltar na posição/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, click

Fiz um botão para abrir uma tela de configuração, quando clico abre a tela, e o botão muda de *"Configuração"* para *"Voltar"*, até aí beleza, mas gostaria que quando clicasse novamente, este voltasse a escrever *"Configuração"*.

Alguém pode me ajudar? De preferência em *jQuery*.

```
$("#settings").hide();
$("#principal").show();
    $("#config").click(function(){
        $("#settings").toggle();
            $("#principal").toggle();
            $(this).html("Voltar");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma condição. Caso o elemento `#settings` esteja visível, mostra um determinado nome, caso contrário exibe outro nome. Ex:

```
/* Caso a div #settings esteja visível, escreve "Voltar" */
if ($("#settings").is(":visible")) {
  $(this).html("Voltar");
}
/* Caso contrário, escreve "Configurações" */
else {
  $(this).html("Configurações");
}
```

**Segue código:**

```js
$("#settings").hide();
$("#principal").show();

$("#config").click(function() {
  $("#settings").toggle();
  $("#principal").toggle();
  
  if ($("#settings").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).html("Voltar");
  } else {
    $(this).html("Configurações");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="settings">settings</div>
<div id="principal">principal</div>

<button id="config">Configurações</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado mestre Valdeir Psr, funcionou perfeitamente.